# how to set a variable to a value with spaces in batch

Tags: batch-file, windows-8

I have a Windows 8 batch file where I am trying to locate a command-line application. For example, this works fine if there are no spaces in the path:

```
for /f %%i in ('where frob.exe 2^>NUL') do set frob=%%i
if [%frob%] == [] (
    @echo frob.exe must be in the path
    goto exit
)
```

But, I want a more general solution that will work even if the path is `c:\this is a test\frob.exe`. So, I tried this:

`for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('where frob.exe 2^>NUL') do set frob=%%i`

But, now I get the error `is was unexpected at this time.`

What do I need to do to get the batch file to correctly interpret complex paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
:: quote the assignment to avoid problems with poison characters
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('where frob.exe 2^>NUL') do set "frob=%%i"

:: quote the value as it can contain spaces
if "%frob%"=="" (
    @echo frob.exe must be in the path
    goto exit
)
```

I think that your problem is in the `if` and not in the `for`

Comment: You're correct; it was the `if` that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims="...
```

By default, the standard separators (like <kbd>Space</kbd> are seleted as "token separators" and by default only the first token is assigned to the metavraiable (`%%i` in your case)

See

```
for /?
```

from the prompt for documentation.

Comment: switching from `"tokens=*"` to `"delims="` made no difference to the error.

Comment: Ah - fixed the wrong error. `tokens=*` and `delims=` are essentially the same - except that the former strips leading separators.